# ejecting cdrom in .net

Tags: .net

using this code:

```
public class DvdRomUtility
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        protected static extern int mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, StringBuilder lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

        public static void Open(string driveName)
        {
            int ret = mciSendString("set cdaudio door open", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        public static void Close(string driveName)
        {
            int ret = mciSendString("set cdaudio door closed", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

i can open and close my dvd rom.
but i want know DVDrom's door is open or close because i want a method to when i call it IF:

1- dvd rom's door is open then dvd rom's door will close

2- dvd rom's door is close then dvd rom's door will open

thanks

Comment: You may want to consider marking the answers to your questions that are clearest and best as Accepted (click the big tick). It helps everyone know immediately what was the best response. Besides, folks around here who have answers Accepted get a boost to their reputation - and it means that you'll get a faster response to questions in the future.

Comment: i done that (sorry for bad english)

Comment: No worries. FWIW MCI doesn't have any way to determine if the drive is open or closed. A brute-force approach might be to use Directory.Exists() on the drive letter for that drive and (ugh) check for an exception. But I'm sure that you can do this more easily through PInvoke to the Windows API.

Comment: hehe, just created an easter egg for the application I'm working on with this code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you take a look at "DeviceIoControl" ? See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(VS.85).aspx) and [P/Invoke.Ne](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/DeviceIoControl.html)t for samples and details, especially the **StorageEjectMedia** and **StorageLoadMedia** commands.

Edit: And for sample code, [it is here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial31_CD-Drive-Control.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [System.IO.DriveInfo.IsReady](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready.aspx) ?